# embedding sound in executable in C++

Tags: c++, audio, wav

how can I store  sound in my executable file? Let's pretend I have function x to play sound located in C:\sounds, how can I store sound.wav inside of executable? do I have to read it byte by byte and hardcode it in some variable, then create file and play it when user executes my file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advice hardcoding the contents of the .wav in some variable and then play it's contents using 'sndPlaySound' with 'SND_MEMORY' option as in this example supplied by Microsoft:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/133064

Comment: sounds good. and you could write a script to fill the variable for you as part of a build system. would keep it updated

Comment: If your target system has a resource system, consider using that instead. Be aware that some (mostly older or embedded) runtime environments can't handle huge amounts of static static, where huge can be as small as 32K.

Comment: @plinth the target system of app is windows XP/vista/7/8, I think they can handle 10 seconds long wav file, can't they? :D

Comment: Hey, that link no longer works :<