# How to Include a sound clip in a release build

Tags: c++, audio

Now that I had some feedback, I see I need to change my question. I would like know how to embed audio into an EXE using console C++ so that anyone can hear the sound when it's on any computer.

At the moment I got a working program that play sounds but the audio file is not embedded in it.

Comment: I don't understand why it being a release build is relevant. Have you had problems? What problems?

Comment: I want to be able to play sound built into the program without having to look in a user folder.

Comment: So go ahead and do so.

Comment: It works on my computer, but I want to include the sound clip directly in the program so when someone else downloads the program it will automatically play the sound clip without any problems.

Comment: Okay so you're asking how to embed audio as a resource into a Visual Studio 2010 -built executable then invoke `PlaySound` on it at runtime.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25997518/560648

Answer (score 0):

It souldn't be any difference from debug and release mode.